# Assume the function has a maximum. Find it. $f(x,y,z)=3-x^2-2y^2-3z^2-2xy-2xz$

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, determinant, hessian-matrix, stationary-point

Putting the first derivatives equal to 0 I get a critical point at C(0,0,0), and then using the second derivatives I get a Determinant of the Hessian matrix=-24. Is C the maximum?

I have a doubt about the determinant. Should I put it in absolute values and look at f11,f22,f33 (which in this case are respectively -2,-4 and -6, so <0) or because it is Det=-24 the point is a saddle point? I am confused because our teacher told us to consider always the determinant in absolute values but in some books I found that when det<0 then the critical point is a saddle point.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hessian of $f$ is
$$H(x,y,z)=-2\begin{bmatrix}
    1 &  1 & 1\\
    1 & 2 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 3
    \end{bmatrix}
.$$
Since ALL the principal minor matrices have positive determinants (they are $1,1,1$), by the [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) and the negative factor $-2$, $H(0,0,0)$ is negative-definite and we may conclude that $(0,0,0)$ is a local maximum point.

The point $(0,0,0)$ is indeed a global maximum because:
$$
\begin{align}f(x,y,z)&=3-\underbrace{\Big(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt{2}y\Big)^2}_{\geq 0}-\underbrace{\Big(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt{2}z\Big)^2}_{\geq 0}-\underbrace{\Big(z\Big)^2}_{\geq 0}\\
&\leq 3=f(0,0,0).
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I ask you what's the theory behind the last formula? "The point (0,0,0) is indeed a global maximum because"

Comment: I just grouped some terms to obtain squares. Actually your function is a quadratic polynomial and there is a method to reduce it to a standard form. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric

Comment: @Jason Have you further doubts?

Answer (score 0):

The Hessian is$$\begin{bmatrix}-2 & -2 & -2 \\ -2 & -4 & 0 \\ -2 & 0 & -6\end{bmatrix},$$whose determinant is $-8$. More generally, its characteristic polynomial is$$P(\lambda)=-\lambda ^3-12 \lambda ^2-36 \lambda -8.$$Clearly, if $\lambda\geqslant0$, $P(\lambda)<0$. Therefore, all three roots of $P(\lambda)$ are all negative. It follows that indeed $f$ has a maximum at $(0,0,0)$.